# Do compact sets always contain a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I was looking at a proof for the Heine-Boral theorem which goes:

1st. Suppose $ A \in \mathbb{R} $ is closed and bounded

therefore, any subsequence $ a_n{_k} \rightarrow L $ (bolzano weierstrass theorem)

For $ a_n \in A $ and we know A is closed, which implies $ L \in A $ which implies A is compact.

2nd. Suppose $ A \in \mathbb{R} $ is compact

Let $ a_n \in A$ be a sequence s.t. $ a_n \rightarrow L $ ***

we know $ \exists\ a_n{_k} \ of \ a_n : a_n{_k} \rightarrow M \in A $ (As A is compact) By uniqueness of limits this implies L = M and therefore $ L \in A$.

(Then we go on to prove compactness implies boundedness)

My issue is with the line ***, when we just assume that there is a sequence in this set that converges. I was wondering if there were any theorems or lemmas that say something along the lines of, we can always find a sequence in a compact set that converges? I am just worried because I know we cannot use the fact the set is closed/bounded yet because that is what we are trying to prove.

I am just very confused about this assumption, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the intent here is to show that any sequence in $C$ that is convergent in $\Bbb R$ has its limit in $C$. That's a criterion for the closedness of $C$.

Comment: (1) Theorem : A sequence of members of a compact subset of  a metric space has a convergent sub-sequence. (2). A topological space $X$ is  a $T_2$ (Hausdorff) space iff whenever$a,b\in X$ with $a\ne b$, there are $disjoint$ open sets $U,V$ with $a\in U$ and $b\in V.$   Theorem:  A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is a closed set. (3). Metric spaces are $T_2.$ And $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric $d(a,b)=|a-b|$ is a metric space. So if $A\subset \Bbb R$ is compact,  a sequence in $A$ has a convergent sub-sequence. And since $A$ is closed, the limit of that sub-sequence belongs to $A.$

Comment: On re-reading your Q, I dk what your issue with *** is. You're  proving in 2) that if $A$ is compact then $A$ is closed. So you prove that IF $(a_n)_n $ is  a convergent sequence in $A$, THEN its limit is in $A$. But if $(a_n)_n $ is convergent then any sub-sequence of it converges to the same limit, so if you already know that ($a_n)_n$ has a sub-sequence converging to some  $M\in A,$  then $(a_n)_n$ must converge to $M$ also.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a set $C$ is close you assume that a sequence $\{c_n\}$ in $C$ converges to a point $C$ and prove that $c \in C$. Of course there is always a constant seqeuence in any non-empty set that is convergent but that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your doubt is a logic question. You are trying to prove an *implication*

$$P\implies Q.$$

An implication is false only when $P$ is true and $Q$ false. Consequence: is irrelevant if *there is some sequence* $a_n\in A$ s.t. $a_n\to L$. You only want that any *hypothetical* sequence verifies that $L\in A$.

In fact, when $P$ is false, $P\implies Q$ is true. In your example this happens when $A = \emptyset$.